# How to find the function of an executed celery task when it has a custom name?

Tags: python, django, celery

I am building an app that is recording and analyzing celery task runs, e.g. to produce statistics. The task runs are recorded through [celery signals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76073186/4379151), so I get a lot of detailed information about each task run including it's ID and name.

Task names can be set to a custom value or - if no value is set - are set to the qualified name of the task's function by default. (e.g. `my_app.tasks.my_task`).

For my app I'd like to keep track of the packages a task belongs to. That is easy to extract when the task's name is the qualified name, but not when it is a custom name. I looked through the data structures provided in each signal call (e.g. sender, request), but could not find any reference to the function that created the task.

I also tried the [registered method](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/reference/celery.app.control.html#celery.app.control.Inspect.registered) in the inspect API, but it appears to contain the same task names and no reference to their functions.

How can I get a reference to the function that created a task from the result of a celery signal or other parts of it's API?

Comment: There is no reference as far as I know, following is just task name as it is simply unique string. I would suggest instead overriding celery register_task method so that named task also follows same structure. It will probably require same on invocation side